# Android resource annotations on a list

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, lint

Is there a way to annotate a list of integers with a resource annotation so that lint shows me an error when I use a method's integer return value wrongly?

Example (`setTextColor()` only takes `@ColorInt`):

```
fun useColor() {
    val textView = TextView(null)
    textView.setTextColor(getColor()) // This correctly shows an error
    textView.setTextColor(getColorList()[0]) // Can I make this show an error too? 
}

@ColorRes
fun getColor() : Int {
    return R.color.black
}

@ColorRes // any way to specify this differently?
fun getColorList() : List<Int>{
    return arrayListOf(R.color.black)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually used my brain a little just now and this is my workaround. Does not answer the question but somewhat solves the problem. Simply reduce the return to a single value:

```
fun useColor() {
    val textView = TextView(null)
    textView.setTextColor(getColorValue(0)) // Correctly show error
}

@ColorRes
fun getColorValue(index : Int) : Int {
    return arrayListOf(R.color.black)[index]
}
```